# How to exclude this particuar class from ProGuard obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

I want to exclude this class from being obfuscated by ProGuard

```
- com.example.myapp.ThisParticularClass.java
```

How can I do that?

I looked into other answers but they are about packages, or class members or using gson annotations

PS: And what if `ThisParticularClass` extends from another class, should I keep the parent class from obfuscation as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use such statement:

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.ThisParticularClass
```

or:

```
-keep public class * extends com.example.myapp.ThisParticularClass
```

Comment: Should I add `keepclassmembers` as well? What is that for? And also should I protect the parent class?

Comment: Remember what `proguard` might do. For example it might replace your `String` constants with random values. `keepclassmembers` prevents for example such case. `-keepattributes` is also useful, when you are using reflection and access methods by name. Each case shoud be handled separately and tested. [Here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/attributes.html) is the documentation of attributes.
As for parent class: I would protect it, but there is nothing that prevents you from checking it by yourself if you really need it.